# Can I use an update query in MS Access to auto-populate a Unique ID field with characters from other fields?

Tags: ms-access, unique-id

Can I  use an update query in MS Access to auto-populate a Unique ID field with characters from other fields? Specifically, I have a unique ID field that consists of (1) last initial of first name (2) first initial of last name (3)mm/dd of DOB and (4) gender (M/F). So John Smith born on Feb 17 would be NS0217M. Is it possible to pull individual characters from an existing field and combine into another field in this manner? I'm working with Access 2003 unfortunately. While I would prefer to create a new ID system, this is the one already in place and I need to tailor the database I'm constructing to suit it.

Comment: Where are you trying to create this Unique ID? The solution by user2063626 will work if you only want it to show up in forms and reports, but won't be saved in it's own field in the database. If You need it saved in a field, then you'll have to use VBA or an update query to create it.

Comment: I'm currently using a form containing these fields to populate a database, so I need the "ClientID" field that's being created to be saved. I'm new to VBA but have used it on a few occasions, I've been unable to find an example of code that would allow me to pull individual characters from multiple fields. From the examples below it looks like there is a way to do this, but I'm unclear where to start. Thank you all for the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you'll use. You'll need to display the UID field on the form, but mark it as locked so you don't accidentally write in it.
Also, this has no error checking, so you'll get errors if any of the fields are blank.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   Me.UID = Right(fname, 1) & Left(lname, 1) & Format(CDate(DOB), "mmdd") & Gender
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

select LEFT(FirstName,1) + RIGHT(LastName,1) + FORMAT(dob,'MMDD') + gender as UniqueID

Comment: `Right(FirstName,1) & Left(LastName,1)`

Comment: Also, in VBA, the correct concatenation character is the &. The + will usually work, but not always. And the Format function wants double quotes.